# Automorphisms of a graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let G be a simple labeled graph with 12 vertices consisting of exactly two connected components which are path graphs on 6 vertices.

```
  o-o-o-o-o-o     o-o-o-o-o-o.
```

I think there are 4 automorphisms.  Reverse one path, reverse the other path, or reverse both paths or do nothing (the identity mapping).
If I try to count the labeleings I get binomial(12,6)*(6!/2)^2 and this is 12!/4.  Everything checks. Right?

However, I am looking at data in Mathematica that says that this graph has 322560 automorphisms.  This would imply 1485 labelings.  Is this nonsense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are $8$ automorphisms.

The $4$ that you found and $4$ extra, they consist of each of the previous $4$ and then swapping the two paths between each other.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  My label count above is wrong. I need to divide binomial(12,6) by 2.  This implies 8 automorphisms as you state.